# Java 7u51: LiveConnect (JavaScript) blocked due to security settings

Tags: java, applet, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

You can check the issue [here](http://ajaxbrowser.com/) by opening twice a .txt file (using double click or "Edit Document") or pressing "Globe".
It won't be opened during second and any further attempt (In Firefox and Chrome). Just a new line appears in Java console:

```
liveconnect: Security Exception: LiveConnect (JavaScript) blocked due to security settings.
```

The certificate is valid:

[image]

And here are strange lines in Console:

```
security: Trust for: http://...OpenDocument.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
```

I tried to add Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute, tried to add a timestamp.

How to satisfy security constrains to avoid this security exception?

**Update1:** The applet can be run once again after reload.

**Update2:** The issue is absent under JRE version 1.7.0_45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding these lines to manifest (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188549/java-7u51-manifest-variables-with-asterisk?rq=1)):

```
Trusted-Library: true
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

Now manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: ...
Permissions: all-permissions
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Main-Class: ...
Codebase: *
```

The issue was fixed both in Windows and MacOS environment.
The `security: Trust for: .jar has ended` problem was not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven use this settings

```
    <build>
  <plugins>
            <!--Set manifest file-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <!--Add manifest properties-->
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
                            <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
                            <Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>*</Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase>
                            <Caller-Allowable-Codebase>*</Caller-Allowable-Codebase>
                            <Codebase>*</Codebase>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use Maven, unfortunately.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. How do I find the manifest file?